# How to retrieve the `scheme://domain` part of an URL without including subdomains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url, dns

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.10 and I would like to retrieve the `scheme://domain` part of an URL without including the subdomain part. That is, if I have the following URL

```
http://www.sub_domain.domain.com
```

I would like to retrieve

```
http://www.domain.com
```

**How can I do that** (should I use a regex?)**?**

---

**UPDATE**

`@mu is too short` rightly said in his\her comment (that made ​​me think...):

> You misunderstand. www.ac.uk is meaningless, the base domain for
>   Oxford is ox.ac.uk; the ac.uk part means "academic UK" and is,
>   semantically, one component. A few other countries have similar naming
>   schemes.

So, the update question is:

**How can I iterate over an URL** (for example `http://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/`) as made in the following steps **so to delete *progressively* subdomain parts until the last?**

```
http://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/ # Step 0 (start)
http://www.ox.ac.uk/       # Step 1
http://www.ac.uk/          # Step 2 (end)
```

Comment: What would you do with something like `http://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/`?

Comment: @mu is too short - Maybe I should iterate the process to get the `http://www.ac.uk/` part or maybe there is a way to get that directly (without iteration).

Comment: You misunderstand. `www.ac.uk` is meaningless, the base domain for Oxford is `ox.ac.uk`; the `ac.uk` part means "academic UK" and is, semantically, one component. A few other countries have similar naming schemes.

Comment: @mu is too short - You are right. So I should iterate over the `http://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/` URL. How can I do that progressively?

Comment: @Backo - The problem with iterating is this: how do you know when you have reached the end?

Comment: @bta - Maybe you can split the URL in to an array and check if the array has size 2 (eg: `['ac','uk']`).

Comment: @Backo - How do you know that 2 is the correct value at which to stop?  In your first example, this would cause the script to think `.domain.com` was the suffix instead of just `.com`, and your output would be the same as your input.  I think mu is on the right track with using DNS lookups to make sure that what you end up with is a valid URL.

Answer (score 0):

This is a total hack, and I have no idea how it could be useful in the generic sense, but here you go.

```
ruby-1.8.7-p352 >   uri = URI.parse("http://www.foo.domain.com/")
 => #<URI::HTTP:0x105011840 URL:http://www.foo.domain.com/> 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 > uri.scheme + "://" + uri.host.split(/\./)[-2..-1].join(".")
 => "http://domain.com"
```

Comment: That will fail on `.uk` domains and a few others.

Comment: Yeah. Like I said, it's terrible and should be avoided. The point of the answer is that you can get the host and split it. Then reassemble the pieces however you want.

Comment: Bascically, the question is too vague to answer. Do you always want to remove the 2nd piece of the host? That's easy. Do you want a generic solution that understands all possible host and sub-host name configurations? That's borderline impossible. What is the real use case here, because there's likely a better way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you *know* that the URL ends in `.com` and follows the format you specified, you could try a regular expression like this:

```
\.[\w\-]+\.com
```

to parse out the domain and the following `.com`.  Prefix that with `http://www` and you should be all set.

There is no "general case" solution for this.  Some URLs use a suffix with one dot (`.com` or `.edu`), while some use multiple dots (`.co.jp`, etc).  You won't be able to solve this with something as simple as a regex.

What you may be able to do is to make a list of possible URL suffixes and construct a regex for each.  If it matches your input string, use a variation of the above:

```
base_regex = '\.[\w\-]+'
list_of_suffixes.each {|s|
    thisregex = Regexp.new(base_regex + s)
    match = thisregex.match(url)
    next if match == nil
    return 'http://www.' + match[0]
}
```

Note: code is off the top of my head and for illustration purposes only (it probably won't run exactly as-is, but you get the point)

Comment: I do *not know* that the URL ends in `.com`.

Comment: @Backo - If you aren't limiting the scope of your input to `.com`, then the problem becomes more complex.  See my edit for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to deal with this is to use [`URI`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI.html):

```
# Parse and remove all the stuff you don't want.
u = URI.parse('http://www.sub-domain.domain.com/pancakes')
u.userinfo = nil
u.path     = ''
u.fragment = nil
# You might want to check u.scheme as well

host = u.host
```

And now you have to figure out what you want to do with `host`. You could start at the last component and work your way backwards until you get a domain name that resolves to something using [Net::DNS](https://github.com/bluemonk/net-dns/):

```
require 'net/dns/resolver'
components = host.split('.')
basename   = (1 .. components.length).
             map  { |i| components.last(i + 1).join('.') }.
             find { |n| Resolver(n).answer.length > 0    }

# basename is now nil or something with a DNS A record
if(basename.nil?)
    # complain and bail out
end
u.host = basename
# Your trimmed URL is in u.to_s
```

You have to check that the domain names resolve to something useful or you won't know if you have a valid one. You could try to track down all the various naming rules all over the world instead but there's no point.

This still won't guarantee you that you have a useful URL, you'd have to check to see if the name you end up with responds to an HTTP request to be sure.

---

To answer your original question:

> should I use a regex?

Absolutely not. URLs are a lot more complicated than most people think so you should use a real URL parser such as [`URI`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI.html). Furthermore, domain names are also more complicated than most people think so you have to resort to DNS lookups to get anything sensible.

Comment: I'll recommend looking at [Addressable::URI](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable/). It is a more capable URI library than Ruby's built-in one, and, especially for this use, its template ability might be very useful. Just use `gem install addressable` to get it.

Comment: @Tin Man: But does it understand that `ac.uk`, `co.jp`, and similar things are single units? The real problem is that the domain in a URL has internal structure beyond a simple "list of components separated by dots" so you can't just pull off the last two components and end up with something meaningful.